# How to conceive a Symfony entity? --> Update of 2 tables in DB with one Symfony form

Tags: forms, symfony, select, collections, entity

I create a Symfony app about "X-Files".

I have several entities among which "Episode" and "Charactor".

Episode has a ManyToMany relation with CharActor.

When I add an episode with the form created in the twig and managed by "EpisodeType", it does not properly update the charactor table. Well, logically, but not really as I wish.

Below is an extract of "_form.html.twig".

form.resume and others before properly update the table "episode".

form.charActors updates the table "charactor", but not properly.

```
<div class="formGroup">
    {{ form_label(form.resume, "Résumé", {"label_attr": {"class": "formLabels"}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.resume, {"attr": {"class": "formWidgets", "rows": "5"}}) }}
</div>
<div class="formGroup">
    {{ form_label(form.charActors, "Personnages/Acteurs", {"label_attr": {"class": "formLabels"}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.charActors, {"attr": {"class": "formWidgetsActors"}}) }}
</div>
```

Below is "EpisodeType".

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\CharActor;
use App\Entity\Episode;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use App\Repository\CharActorRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class EpisodeType extends AbstractType
{
    private $charActorRepository;
    public function __construct(CharActorRepository $charActorRepository)
    {
        $this->charActorRepository = $charActorRepository;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('numberSeason', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('numberEpisode', IntegerType::class)
            ->add('originalTitle', TextType::class)
            ->add('frenchTitle', TextType::class)
            ->add('frenchDiff', DateType::class, [
                "widget" => "choice",
                "format" => "d M y",
                "years" => range(1993, 2019)])
            ->add('scenario', TextType::class)
            ->add('realisation', TextType::class)
            ->add('resume', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('charActors', EntityType::class, [
                "multiple" => true,             // Permet de faire plusieurs sélections.
                "class" => CharActor::class,    // Recherche les choix dans cette entité.
                "choice_label" => "name",       // Utilise cette propriété comme option visible.
            ])
            ->add('image', TextType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Episode::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

What is wrong is that in my charactor table, which has the fields "name" (with a string such as "Agent Scully : Gillian Anderson") and "episodesNb" (with an array such as ["1-01","1-02","1-03"]), it creates a new line with these 2 fields empty.

But what I would like to obtain would be, if for example I select Scully in the EntityType, to update the array in "episodesNb" with the new episode number and have as a result ["1-01","1-02","1-03", "1-04"].

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As a web developer you should be expected know the basics of asking questions on stackoverflow.  In particular, opinion based questions are frowned upon and closed quite quickly.  Consider posting on something like [Symfony Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/symfony/new/).  But delete at least 90% of your words before doing so.  Just narrowing the focus of your question will probably help you out quite a bit as well.

Comment: It was the first time I posted a question here... What I expected was a little more help. I know I have made a very long post, but I just wanted it to be as clear as possible. I will do better next time...

Comment: A much shorter description of your app and more focus on the problem would definitely help. And yes, you should revise your data model and introduce a many2many link between episode and character.

Comment: Thank you simon.ro for your help. You confirmed what I thought about these 2 entities but as the Symfony doc page I talked about didn't mention it in its "Task/Tag" example, I wasn't sure if it was necessary or even better... But now, it seems I have a "real" coding problem with this collection. So, if I don't solve it by myself, I will redo this question with the new matter. Anyway, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you have a coherent model for your need as mentioned @simon.ro , such as:

```
class Episode

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Settings\Domain\Character")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="episode_character",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="episode_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="character_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private Collection $attachedCharacters;
```

Your type just need to look like that :

```
->add('attachedCharacters', EntityType::class, [
 'choices' => $this->charatersRepository->findAll(),
 'choice_value' => 'fullName',
 'multiple' => true
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works how you wrote it with "choices" and "choice_value" but I came back to "class" and "choice_label". I have made a ManyToMany relation between the 2 entities but when I add an episode with this EntityType, the new table "episode_charactor" with the fields "episode_id" and "charactor_id" stays empty, which shouldn't be the case, logically. I must have forgotten something. And moreover, I must add a way to let the possibility to add a character, so as to update the charactor table. Rome wasn't made in a day, they say !! ;-)

Comment: How do you handle submit request for your form? Do you have values when you adding attachedCharacters at least? 
I didn't mentioned in my previous answer but if you want update your collection when you update because you said your are Symfony developer but need to add the persist decorator of Doctrine if you update your collection automaticly such has 
`
, cascade={"persist"} 
`
See : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/cookbook/decorator-pattern.html#persisting-the-decorator-pattern

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't understand everything in what you wrote juste above. But please if you can and want, read the edit I made for my question. It's shorter and the problem I have is specific... Thanks !

Comment: 1 . Check if you post well your "CharActor" when you submit your form.
2.  Add argument persist on you collection:  ` , cascade={"persist"}
3. RTFM : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/cookbook/decorator-pattern.html#persisting-the-decorator-pattern

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I'll do my best...